# Getting the body of individual emails from gmail to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm really new at using Google Apps Script, so if what I'm trying doesn't make sense, or just isn't possible please let me know.

Everyday I get several emails that look like the following:

> Your Name: FirstName LastName
>
> Phone Number: 555 867 5309
>
> Email Address: FakeEmail@email.com
>
> What do you need help with? Request someone makes.

I'm attempting to automatically send the body of these emails to a new line in a Google Sheet when they come in.

As of right now I have every email get the label "myLabel" when it comes in.  I then run the following script, which is a slightly modified version of something I found here:

```
    function myFunction() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

      var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
      var threads = label.getThreads();

      for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
      {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

        for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
        {
         var msg = messages[j].getBody();

          ss.appendRow([msg])
        }
          threads[i].removeLabel(label);
      }
    }
```

I'm attempting to run this code with a timer trigger every 15 minutes.  The issue I've run into is that every time the code runs it pulls from every email in the thread. I would like it to just pull from the emails that are new since the last time it ran.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the [GmailApp.search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String))

Comment: [Search operators you can use with Gmail-Gmail Doc](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) might also be useful.

Comment: I've tried using Gamil.App.search() it still presents me with the issue that it grabs every email in the thread, and not the specific emails I'm trying to get.  I elaborated on the problem in another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693183/how-to-get-the-body-of-individual-emails-based-on-a-label-from-gmail-to-google-s/56705764?noredirect=1#comment99979526_56705764) that I think explains the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Why not mark the messages as read when you finish processing them? Here is a sample from one of my scripts.

```
  var pendingEmailLabel = "MyLabel";
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(pendingEmailLabel).getThreads();
  for (var t = 0; t < threads.length; ++t) {
    var thread = threads[t];
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; ++m) {
      var message = messages[m];
      if (message.isUnread()) {
          // INSERT YOUR CODE HERE THAT TAKES ACTION ON THE MESSAGE
          message.markRead();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```