# How to get the body of individual emails based on a label from gmail to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Every day I get 0-20 emails that look basically like this:

> Name: FirstName LastName
>
> Phone Number: 555-867-5309
>
> Email Address: Fake@email.com
>
> Location: NameOfPreferedBranch
>
> Request: ThingPersonWants

I'm attempting to get the body of these emails sent to different Google Sheets based on the location listed.  So if the person filling out the form says that Location1 works for them I'd like the message body sent to Location1's Sheet. 
 If the person says Location2 then the message body should go to location2's sheet, and so on.  Every time one of these emails comes in I have Gmail apply a different label based on the location. Ideally I'd like to set up a trigger that runs every 15 minutes and does't duplicate results that have already been run through the process.

I've found some code on other questions similar to this that gets me frustrating close, but I can't seem to get this quite right.  Here is what I'm working with currently:

```
    function myFunction() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NameOfSheet');

      var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
      var threads = label.getThreads();

      for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
      {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

        for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
        {
          if (messages[j].isUnread())
              {
                var msg = messages[j].getBody();      
                sheet.appendRow([msg]);
                messages[j].markRead();
              }
        }
          threads[i].removeLabel(label);
      }
    }
```

I was hoping the combination of getting the threads by the label and the

```
    if (messages[j].isUnread())
```

section would get me just the messages that had the label and hadn't been read, but it's still returning all the messages in the entire thread.  Additionally it's marking all the messages in the thread as read which means that if Location1 and Location2 both have a message in the thread when the script runs for Location1's sheet it marks all of the messages as read, and when the script runs for Location2's sheet it doesn't pull anything because all the messages are already marked as read.

As is probably pretty obvious by now I'm really new with Google Apps Scripts and coding in general. If you could use short words and painfully detailed explanations in you answers it would help out a lot.

Thanks.

Edit: I tried to use `GmailApp.search()` but am still getting the same results.  It pulls the body from every email in the thread and marks them all as Unread.  This is what the code looks like at present:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NameOfSheet');

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Location1Label");
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Location1Label" is:Unread');

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      if (messages[j].isUnread())
          {
            var msg = messages[j].getBody();      
            sheet.appendRow([msg]);
            messages[j].markRead();
          }
    }
      threads[i].removeLabel(Location1Label);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in your last question of using `GmailApp.search()` ?

Comment: I tried.  I would either get a error message that said 'Missing ) after argument list', and when I added one it would say the same thing, or if I got it to run it didn't appear to do anything.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I haven't been able to track down what it is...mostly because when I find answers from searching I can't understand what they're explaining because I don't know enough.

Comment: Could you add the example of `GmailApp.search()` to your question so that we can troubleshoot it?

Comment: The version that I thought was going to get me there was `var messages = GmailApp.search('label:"Location1Label" && is:Unread');` but when I run that nothing  appears to happen.  If I leave out the ' ' I get the error message "Missing ) after argument list'

Comment: Your issue is because you're using && in the search string. You should be building this like you would in the search bar at the top of your Gmail. `var messages = GmailApp.search('label:"Location1Label" is:unread');`

Comment: I removed the &&.  Still having the same problem.  Added an edit above to hopefully explain better.

Comment: Added an answer that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Requirement:

Find all emails inside a label that are unread and add to sheet.

---

#### Solution:

Use a query passed to `GmailApp.search()` to find all of the unread messages inside a label.

Here's the script:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NameOfSheet');

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Location1Label");
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Location1Label" is:Unread');

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) 
  {
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) 
    {
      if (messages[j].isUnread())
      {
        var msg = messages[j].getBody();      
        sheet.appendRow([msg]);
        messages[j].markRead();
      }
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

Now we're using `GmailApp.search()` to find all of the emails, then passing looping through the result array and passing each object to `GmailApp.getMessagesForThread()`.

The rest of the code is unchanged except for your `removeLabel()` as it wasn't looking at the variable you defined earlier in the script.

---

#### References:

1. [`.search()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String))
2. [`.getMessagesForThread()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getMessagesForThread(GmailThread))

Comment: I think I see what you are doing, and I suspect I haven't explained my intentions well enough. I'm not trying to find all emails inside a label that are unread and add to sheet. I'm trying to find all the emails that have a specific label and add them to a sheet, and then use their read or unread status to make sure when the program runs again it doesn't return results that have already been added to the sheet.  Your solution returns all the unread emails from any thread that contains the label in question, but I only want the emails with the label.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah - not quite sure I understand your requirement. Do you mean you only want to return the individual emails that have the label applied rather than the whole thread of emails?

Comment: Yes.  So if I have 5 new emails and two get labeled "Location1Label" another two get "Location2Label" and the last one gets "Location3Label" and they are all in the same thread I would like the program to only get the body of the emails labeled Location1 and also only mark the emails with the label Location1 as read so that I can run a similar program for Location2 later and get the emails from that location in another sheet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you can't give individual messages inside a thread their own label - the label is applied to the whole thread itself, hence why there's no `getLabel()` method for [Class GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message). Could you show what you mean by giving each email in a thread a different label?

Comment: [Picture of the part of the Inbox I'm working with](https://imgur.com/a/UFFhGy0)  Maybe I'm trying to use labels in a way they won't work.  Is it possible to just get the body of an email into sheets based on the content of the email?